# Having trouble retrieving JSON from res

Tags: json, node.js, express, mongoose

I'm using node, express, and mongoose.

I have a function that performs a search in a database and sends the response in a JSON format with:

```
res.jsonp(search_result);
```

This displays the correctly returned result in the browser as a JSON object. My question is, how do I get that JSON object?

I've tried returning search_result but that gives me null (possibly because asynchronous). I'd also like to not edit the current function (it was written by someone else). I'm calling the function and getting a screen full of JSON, which is what res.jsonp is supposed to do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you want to get json?

Comment: I want to retrieve it in my server code.

So I'm calling some search function search() which ends up calling res.jsonp(search_result) which displays the json in my browser as a response. I want to access this JSON in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a new function that takes this JSON as parameter and place it inside the old one. Example:

```js
// Old function
app.get('/', function(req,res){

  // recieve json
  json_object = .....

  // Get json to your function
  processJson(json_object);

  // Old function stuff
  .
  .
  .

});

function processJson(json_object) {

  // Here you'll have the existing object and can process it
  json_object...

}
```

Comment: This would be great, but my entire issue is how to get the JSON object. 

Do I just use a callback and return the object?

Comment: jsonp has callback itself , you can write ' var jsn = res.jsonp(search_result);' and you will have it :)